# Jquery Sortable and Dragable - Replace dragged content with Ajax result

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

This is probably a simple question, but how can I replace the thing I am dragging with html from an ajax call?

So, if the draggable items are just 'text' items (as below in the html snippet), and when I drag the thing I use a 'image' via the helper method, how can I 'on drop' not use either of them but insert the html as returned from a ajax call.

Where do I make the call (btw, using the 'input-type' value to the ajax call to get the correct html)?

How to I prevent the default 'dragged item' from being inserted? I.e. I don't want the div put in or the helper method image....

Do I need to add like a `droppable` or do I do this in the `sortable` on like the `received` event (kind of works, can't remove image but from help method)??? (I have been trying both, and whilst the ajax call worked and I get the data etc, given that I don't know how to prevent the default stuff being dropped I am not sure 'what' I am replacing with the 'result' from the call...)

```
$("#desktoplayout").sortable({
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).append('<div>html from ajax call</div>'); // kind of works... but the image from the 'helper method' on the 'draggable' is still there.
    }
});   // A sortable list of stuff into which things are dragged.

var input-type;

$("#draggableItems .item").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#desktoplayout",
    helper: function (event) {
        return "<div class='item'><img src='/Images/Header.png' /></div>";
    },
    start: function (event, ui) {
        input-type = $(this).find('.preview').data("input-type");
    },
    drag: function(e, t) {
    },
    stop: function(e, t) {
    }
});
```

and

```
<div id="draggableItems">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="preview" data-input-type="1">
            TEXT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

This seems to do what I wanted... is calling `remove` on the `helper` the correct way of doing this?

```
receive: function(event, ui) {
    ui.helper.remove();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.get("somewhere", function(data) {
        // Note: presume more logic here.....
        $($this).append(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of one solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zh9szubf/

**HTML**

```
<div id="draggableItems">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="preview" data-input-type="1">
      TEXT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ul id="desktoplayout">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#desktoplayout").sortable({
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      var newItem;
      $.post("/echo/html/", {
        html: "<li class='newItem'>From Ajax</li>"
      }, function(data) {
        ui.helper.replaceWith(data);
      });
    }
  });

  var inputType;

  $("#draggableItems .item").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#desktoplayout",
    helper: function (event) {
      return "<div class='item'><img src='/Images/Header.png' /></div>";
    },
    start: function(event, ui) {
      inputType = ui.helper.find('.preview').data("input-type");
    }
  });
});
```

This will work with `$.get()` too, but for the example, it had to be `$.post()`. Basically, whatever you want top be the result, That code should be in the `ui.helper.replaceWith()` section.

Comment: Also updated to include the `inputType` data: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zh9szubf/4/

Comment: A little more fancy on the various states: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zh9szubf/5/

Comment: More code cleaning and found a bug when grabbing the `TEXT` versus the box itself: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zh9szubf/6/